# ActiveAdmin add current admin as author

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activeadmin

I've got a pretty simple Post model I'm exposing through ActiveAdmin. Is it possible to attribute a Post on create to an author (the current ActiveAdmin user)? In a regular controller I'd just use:

```
@post = Post.new(params[:post])
@post.author = user
@post.save
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your application.rb you should check this line:

```
config.current_user_method = :current_user
```

By default I think the line usually reads

```
config.current_user_method = :current_admin_user
```

In that case you would want to use that method in the controller. To create a custom controller in Active Admin you can do something like this in your admin/post file:

```
controller do
  def create
    @post.user = current_admin_user
     super
  end
```

Comment: Correction: `config.current_user_method` is in `config/initializers/activeadmin.rb`.

Answer (score -1):

You can use callback in Post model, example:

```
before_save :set_author
def set_author
    self.author = current_user
end
```

Or you can modify update action in ActiveAdmin controller
http://activeadmin.info/docs/8-custom-actions.html#modifying-the-controller